# Importing Excel into SS2000; Error on Field; DTS

Tags: excel, import, sql-server-2000, dts

I'm trying to import an excel file in to a SQL Server 2000 database using DTS. This is nothing fancy, just a straight import. Where I work, we do this 1000 times a day. This procedure usually works without an issue but something must have changed in the file.

I'm getting the below error:

[Screen shot of Error http://www.understandingguitar.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/packageerror-screenshot-20081212.jpg](http://www.understandingguitar.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/packageerror-screenshot-20081212.jpg)

I've checked to ensure that the column "AssignmentID" is stored as "text" in the excel sheet. I've also tried to change it to general. Exact same error regardless of setting. The field does contain numbers... I appreciate everyone's help on this!

Regards, 
Frank

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225052(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer** has something to do with the fact that the procedure is expecting text but even if you set the properties (in the format dialog) to "text", excel may not handle the data as text. And hence, SQL Server (or the libraries) won't handle it to text.

When the procedures try to import it, the system feels that it is converting from a number to text and it expect that data maybe lost (even though no data will be lost) and the error is raised.

**If figured out that I can get around this error by placing a ' (apostrophe) before each listed number.** [I.E. '124321] This force excel to treat the number as text.

Hopefully this will save others the headache I now have from this. :-)

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Try opening at the excel file and see the column content.
Is any of the row value in that column right-aligned? (generally for numbers)?

I am guessing that such a row could be a problem.

Comment: Its not an alignment problem and as my issue description states, I've tried to "store" the text as text (excel option) and I've tried to store it as general...

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious, but is the destination string long enough to hold the string representation of the float? I'm not sure if Excel is rounding what it displays to you, so  it may be worth trying with a wider column.